# sql: How many times inner select query we can write in select statements in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example,

select ......(select.......(select....))))

Comment: Which database are you using? The answer will change depending. For instance Oracle can have 255 nested subqueries: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries007.htm

Comment: I would advise against going too deep, and if you're already deep with certain queries rewrite them to use CTE's or use temporary tables instead of derived tables. The query optimizer will go bonkers in certain scenarios where your structure is too deep. Even CTE's won't cut it sometimes...

Answer (score 0):

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575.aspx

> A subquery can be nested inside the WHERE or HAVING clause of an outer
>   SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement, or inside another
>   subquery. Up to 32 levels of nesting is possible, although the limit
>   varies based on available memory and the complexity of other
>   expressions in the query. Individual queries may not support nesting
>   up to 32 levels. A subquery can appear anywhere an expression can be
>   used, if it returns a single value.